# A tag will not wrap the whole span

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a strange issue with logo at that [site](http://serwer1595633.home.pl/wolnomularstwo.pl).
The logo at top left hand side is made like that:

```
<div id="logo">
                <a href="">
                <span id="logo1"></span>
                <span id="logo2"></span>
                <span id="logo3"></span>
                </a>
</div>
```

where spans have sizes and display: inline-block
yet only about a half of the first span is clickable and nothing that I do seems to help resolve this issue.

What's going on?

(I know there are some small html validation errors but hey, this is wordpress :) )

Comment: You should fully include the relevant code, without linking to your site.

Comment: @nicael. Believe me I would prefer to...

Comment: @nicael. I was not possible because every single thing it that site could have been the reason for the strange behavior as this was not a standard thing to expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add in your style.css line number 72  `z-index: 9999;`

```
#logo {
    position: fixed;
    padding: 1em;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
    margin-top: -21px;
    width: 38%;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: Wow. How did you figure that out? What was covering it?